# Is there any way to make polylines clickable? (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xamarin

I would to click the polyline and make something with it (like show info window). There is no problem with marker (.MarkerClick or OnMapClick(LatLng point)) but I cant find a way how to make polyline clickable :( I need any help.

I code in Xamarin(C#), not Android Studio(java).

Comment: I code in Xamarin(C#), not Android Studio(java).

Comment: The APIs and algorithm are the same.  Translating 10 lines of code from java to C# should be trivial